# why session time out not set in web.config and code behind file

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

In my  project.I am using webforms in my application.SomeWhere I am using update panel and some where i am working without update panel.But the problem  I am facing is session time out.Sometimes when i click on button which is inside my update panel then instantly session out.when i press F5 or ctrl+f5 also my session lost.In all my application session is not working properly either i am using update panel or not.I  putted the  time   = "500" in  my web.config file.

```
<sessionState timeout = "500" mode = "InProc" />
```

but session  is not working why?

I need to change application pool session state time out also or not?

Comment: Have you tried to debug you server side code? (I assume code is solid and does not have issues like StackOverflow which obviously will case app-domain to recycle and lose all in-memory state including sessions)... The fact that just refreshing page in browser causes sessions to be lost is strange - make sure that session cookie is sent correctly (use Fiddler or any other HTTP watcher/debugger to confirm).

Comment: for start, use database to save you session.

Comment: Yes code is correct and all the thing is correct

Comment: I need to change application pool session state time out also or not?

Comment: I did not change the application pool session state